# using custom datatypes to change EditorFor MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, templates, razor, types

I want to use EditorForModel() to generate my view, but I want some control over the datatypes but only for some given fields. What ive tried to do is setup a custom type for my ID field which I don't want to be editable. So far I can not get my template to take effect for my custom data type.

so my model

```
public static customer Createcustomer(global::System.Int32 id, global::System.String code, global::System.Boolean data, global::System.Int32 vehtotal)
    {
        customer customer = new customer();
        customer.id = id;
        customer.code = code;
        customer.data = data;
        customer.vehtotal = vehtotal;
        return customer;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Primitive Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// No Metadata Documentation available.
    /// </summary>
    [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=false)]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    [DataType("myCustomID")]
    public global::System.Int32 id
    {
        get
        {
            return _id;
        }
        set
        {
            OnidChanging(value);
            ReportPropertyChanging("id");
            _id = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value);
            ReportPropertyChanged("id");
            OnidChanged();
        }
    }
```

my View

```
@model Models.customer

@{
   ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}


<h2>Edit</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>customer</legend>

    @Html.EditorForModel()

 <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
```

}

my view for customid field

```
    @model .Models.customer


@{
ViewBag.Title = "myCustomID";
}

<h2>myCustomID</h2>

<p>
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.id)

</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

> What ive tried to do is setup a custom type for my ID field which I don't want to be editable

You could decorate it with the `[HiddenInput]` attribute:

```
[EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=false)]
[DataMemberAttribute()]
[HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
public global::System.Int32 id
```

Note that this will still include the field but as a hidden field. The user can still forge a request and change its value. Do not use this for any security assertions.